# $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous and $f(\mathbb{R}$) is countable, then $f$ is constant.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $f(\mathbb{R}$) is countable. Show that $f$ is constant.

Some ideas: proving the contrapositive. To suppose that $f$ is not constant and to use the intermediate value theorem to prove that $f(\mathbb{R})$ is not countable.

Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The image of a connected space under a continuous map is connected.  The only connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are one-point sets and intervals, but intervals are uncountable.  QED.

Answer (score 5):

If $x,y\in f(\Bbb R)$ and $x<y$, then $[x,y]\subset f(\Bbb R)$.

Answer (score 5):

If $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, then it satisfies the intermediate value property on $\mathbb{R}$.  That is, if $a < b$ and $y$ is between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, then there exists some $c \in (a,b)$ such that $f(c)$ is between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$.

If $f$ takes more than one value, say $f(a) \ne f(b)$ (in fact, assume without loss of generality that $f(a) < f(b)$), then for any value $y\in (f(a),f(b))$, there must be some $c\in (a,b)$ such that $f(c) = y$.  But the interval $(f(a),f(b))$ is uncountable, thus if a continuous function takes more than one value, then it's range must be uncountable.

From this it follows that if a continuous function takes only countably many values, then it must be constant.